Dymola showing "Command cannot be executed" by verifing C Compiler
I'm new to Dymola and configuring the environment. After installing the Dymola I should verify the C Compiler. I've installed both the Visual Studio 2019 and the MinGW GCC. But form the Simulation Setup pageI can not verify the Compiler (the option for Visual Studio 2019 doesn't show up, and the MinGW GCC cannot be verified, see screenshoot).

The Visual Studio 2019 is working. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Assuming that the compilers are in fact installed one possibility would be that they are installed in some other place.

Is mingw installed on C: in those directories? Otherwise change the path(s).
Same for Visual Studio 2019; if it is installed in some other place just add that under "Visual Studio Custom".

Another is that there's something odd with running programs in general - the log-file (as show in the log-tab) could give hints.

After installing the "MSVC v140..." by the Visual Studio Installer and configuring the "Visual Studio Custom", the problem is solved. Thanks.
